# Shortest route for a Nitrogen atom from fossil fuel to a protein in your body?

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, homework, ecology

> Millions of years ago fossil fuels originated from plants. A nitrogen
>   atom from fossil fuel is now inside in a protein molecule in your
>   body. What is the shortest path that the nitrogen atom could have
>   taken starting with plants that lived millions of years ago, until the
>   protein molecule in your body. Use those points:
>
> - consumers
> - producers
> - reducers
> - fossil fuels
> - $NO_x$

I guess the route could be producers -> reducers -> fossil fuels -> consumers -> $NO_x$

But this could be wrong, because NO does not have to be produced by consumers.

Comment: producers-reducers-fossil fuels-NO-producers-consumers.

Comment: fossil fuel is out of question.. it is a byproduct not a precursor for a metabolite.. atmospheric nitrogen can be fixed to nitrate by physicochemical or biochemical processes

Comment: Fossil fuel -combustion-> NOx -deposition-> plant -> person